# How to change default error search in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

While I was writing my code in **Visual Studio 2015CTP** I got error as below in ErrorList window:

> Error  CS0117  'Console' does not contain a definition for 'ReadKey'

By clicking on `CS0117` it redirects me to default browser and searches using Bing. As most of the time we use Google as a search engine, is there any way to make Google as a default search instead of Bing.

Comment: I use this Chrome extension to redirect ALL search requests from bing to google:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg

In configuration I have from: "www.bing.com/search?q"
to: "www.google.com/search?q" ...suddenly I don't mind MS pushing Bing everywhere :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply redirecting the search provider probably won’t work. We generate a search string that is tailored to work with a specialized search engine on the Bing side. Passing that same search string to another search engine probably will give poor results.

What you will need to do, instead, is define your own handler for the help event. This would extract relevant information from the error itself (such as error code, language, etc.) to create a generic search that would work with the provider of your choice. If this handler comes before the default handler, then you can handle the event and prevent the default (bing) search from executing.

The interfaces your need to implement are:

[`ITableControlEventProcessorProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.tablecontrol.itablecontroleventprocessorprovider.aspx)

This is a MEF export and should have the following attributes:

```
[Export(typeof(ITableControlEventProcessorProvider))]
[DataSourceType(StandardTableDataSources.ErrorTableDataSourceString)]
[DataSource(StandardTableDataSources.AnyDataSourceString)]
[ManagerIdentifier(StandardTables.ErrorsTableString)]
[Name("my custom event processor name")]
[Order(Before=Priority.Default)]
```

[`ITableControlEventProcessor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.tablecontrol.itablecontroleventprocessor.aspx)

It is probably best to define a class that is derived from
[`TableControlEventProcessorBase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.tablecontrol.tablecontroleventprocessorbase.aspx) (which provides default/no-op implementations for all of the events) and then explicitly handle the [`PreprocessNavigateToHelp(ITableEntryHandle entry, TableEntryEventArgs e)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.tablecontrol.tablecontroleventprocessorbase.preprocessnavigatetohelp.aspx) event by:

1. extracting the useful data from entry
2. creating a generic search to the search provider of your choice
3. opening an instance of the browser
4. setting `e.Handled` to true (to prevent the other help handlers from executing).

Comment: based on your phrasing I am assuming you are involved with this tool. Hopefully you can communicate this to the team in some way, but the search results I get from the error links in VS 2015 are completely useless. They are so hard to sort out and most of the time they return irrelevant information or just nothing useful at all.
I have far more success just copying the error data and searching google. 
I am saying this because I wish the tool would work. It is a great idea. In practice I completely stay away from those links because they are so frustrating.

Comment: "Passing that same search string to another search engine probably will give poor results." Please let users decide what is the best for them, not imposing a "good" search engine that fits the search...

Comment: [@Serge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961631), you’re misinterpreting what [David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255348) said. The search string is “tailored to work with a specialized search engine on the Bing side”. That’s why using that string elsewhere will give poor results.

Answer (score 2):

There’s no built-in support for switching the search engine used. It is, however, possible to create an extension that lets Google (and other) search engines be linked to instead, just as the Bing Developer Assistant extension did in previous releases of Visual Studio.

I'd point you to the docs with info on how to create such an extension, but they're not published yet. They're on the list of docs to be published around the time Visual Studio 2015 is officially released.

Comment: Will ping the team and follow up. Thanks for the nudge, @Serge.

Comment: What disgusts me is that all these involuntary Bing searches from Visual Studio or Start Menu Search should be counted as legitimate search traffics, which Microsoft would use to boast the market share of Bing.

Answer (score 2):

Another quick hack that I just made would be a browser script.
I used Greasemonkey to generally redirect searches from Bing to Google.
Because who the hell has ever chosen the former over the latter...

If you have Greasemonkey installed or other places to use a userscript, you can use

```
// @include     http://www.bing.com/search?q=*
var rex = /\?q=(.+)/;
window.location.href = ("http://www.google.com/#safe=off&q="+window.location.href.match(rex)[1]);
```

to always redirect from Bing to Google.

Not really a VS answer, but a work-around. And in my case, it seems just fine since I prefer Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by setting up a hosts entry to 127.0.0.1 for bingdev.cloudapp.net and use the IIS URL Rewrite module to redirect your request to google.

I went into more detail on my [blog post here](http://www.kiasyn.com/google-in-visual-studio-2015/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this comment above from Ondrej Petrzilka Dec 19 '15 and it works really well, thank you very much.

1. Search and install this chrome extension
   switcheroo-redirector
2. Restart Chrome
3. Click on the extension icon on top right of Chrome, then click Switcheroo.
   [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxgvM.png)
4. Setup from: "www.bing.com/search?q" to: "www.google.com/search?q". [Screenshot here[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgZ4Q.png)

Comment: that is a good idea but your extension didn't work. I am using this https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrometana-pro-redirect-c/lllggmgeiphnciplalhefnbpddbadfdi/reviews