# Visual Studio opens error details in Bing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, google-search, bing

When I compile my project in `Visual Studio 2015` and have an error in the error list. In the `Code` column there is a link to that error, doing a search of the error message in... **Bing**...

Is there a way to change that behavior to the (usual) **Google**'s search engine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change default error search in Visual Studio 2015](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594649/how-to-change-default-error-search-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: but no answer, the question is a little obsolete (not really the same version of visual studio)