# How to customize error code link in MSBuild tasks

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, msbuild-task

I am writing an MSBuild task and I log errors using `Log.LogError` as follows

```
Log.LogError(
    "MyTaskErrorCategory",
    "A0001",
    "MyKeyword",
    ...,
    "My error message"
```

In the example above I log an error with error code "A0001". When Visual Studio dysplays the error and I try to click on the error code, the link directs to the VS page using the "MyKeyword" search keywrod.

My question is: is there a way to change the link on the VS error code so that it directs users to my custom website?

Thanks in advance,
Fabio.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a future version of MSBuild may support a [helpLink] in the future.

[MSBuild helpLink](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/5488)

Besides that I unfortunately I don't think it's possible.  The third parameter for log error is defined as

> **helpKeyword** *String*
>
> The help keyword for the host IDE (can be null).

So from that this change would be a Visual Studio setting if opening from visual studio and I don't think they provide the option to do that.  The thread below may provide a valid work around for you.

[How to change default error search in visual studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594649/how-to-change-default-error-search-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: While I do appreciate the answer, it's probably not a visual studio setting. Some errors point to different URLs, only "hand-made" errors seemingly do not. Note that, while the page you linked talkes about a redirect fom bing to google, My error-codes always point to https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev16.query?k=k(My-Keyword-Here)

Comment: What version of visual studio are you running?

Comment: Looks like a future MS build version may support that.

https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/5488

Comment: 2019 (Professional)